# javascript function execution from Magento static cms block

Tags: javascript, magento

I have a problem getting on click function executed from external link inside static Magento CMS block.

Link on static block :Details

Traget page has accordion items that closed.  I'm trying to open one item using external link.
this is the function on target page(this works inside console, but not from external link):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    function charges(){ 
    jQuery('[name="ShiptoStore"]').addClass('open');
    jQuery('div.jq-accordion-body:eq(17)').css('display','block');

    jQuery('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: jQuery("#targcharge").offset().top
    }, 800)

    }
    });
```

Only jquery commands work inside console.

Comment: Sorry, got link cut off:

Comment: <a href="target_page"  onclick="charges();return false;">Details</a>